is it possible to add a stepwise counter for assigning a number to each text block?
Basically I want to have a number assign to each paragraph in the document at document level . That means not having to define a script at paragraph level. No each 'paragraph' in the document has \paragraph tag. So Is there a way to run a stepwise counter i.e. integer 1 to N to assign a number of each paragraph in the whole document for output pdf?
Input:
\section{section one}
This is a general text describing trees in tropical forets. The trees are categorized into....
This is a general text describing insects in tropical forets. The insects are categorized into....
This is a general text describing fish in tropical forets. The fishes are categorized into....
This is a general text describing waters in tropical forets. The waters are categorized into....
Expected output:
Section one

This is a general text describing trees in tropical forets. The trees are categorized into....

This is a general text describing insects in tropical forets. The insects are categorized into....

This is a general text describing fish in tropical forets. The fishes are categorized into....

This is a general text describing waters in tropical forets. The waters are categorized into....



yes. you can number paragraphs pretty easily. on recent kernels, it got even easier. you just need to use the paragraph hooks the kernel now provides with a custom counter. I usually put the typeset numbers in the margin, but that's just a layout thing.

however, your input would have to include a preamble and a document environment. (and the class you are using may matter.) also, you should say if you're using a package to typeset critical editions, because then you'd need to work consistently with that.

Recently there was a similar question, and you will certainly find more on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725414/245790

@MS-SPO swept through the site looking for a question/answer but didn't find what I want. So the below answers exactly what I was after instead of meddling with existing sectional tags and structural components that I do not wish to break as a novice.

@cfr can the preamble be an overleaf document class where all the packages are put in?

@bonCodigo yes.

Update This version attempts to enable paragraph numbering automatically at the start of the document and to suspend numbering automatically for sections, subsections etc. (If you are using book or report, say, you would want to add chapter, at least.)
\nopars explicitly turns paragraph numbering on and \plainpars turns it off, so it can be disabled and reenabled as necessary. Numbers are set in the left margin and incremented for every paragraph for which they are enabled.
This version uses a boolean to track whether to number the current paragraph or not, which is simpler than trying to add and remove code from hooks. So the code sits in the hook regardless, but it only does anything if the boolean is true. Hence, it is easy to switch numbering on and off as needed.
I said this was easier with hooks but, actually, it is probably harder. It should, however, be more robust.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726112/
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newcounter{paracnt}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\int_new:N \g__nopars_para_int
\bool_new:N \g__nopars_nos_bool
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \nopars__no_pars:
{
  \bool_if:NT \g__nopars_nos_bool
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__nopars_para_int
    \llap{
      \int_to_arabic:n {
        \g__nopars_para_int \skip_horizontal:n { 5pt }
      }
    }
  }
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument / end } { nopars }
{
  \hook_gput_code:nnn {para/begin} { nopars }
  {
    \nopars__no_pars:
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \nopars {}
{
  \bool_gset_true:N \g__nopars_nos_bool
}
\NewDocumentCommand \plainpars {} {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g__nopars_nos_bool
}
\clist_map_inline:nn { section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph, part }
{
  \hook_gput_code:nnn {cmd/#1/before}{ nopars }
  {
    \bool_gset_false:N \g__nopars_nos_bool
    \hook_gput_next_code:nn { para / begin }
    {
      \bool_gset_true:N \g__nopars_nos_bool
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
% \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{section one}

This is a general text describing trees in tropical forests.
The trees are categorized into\dots

This is a general text describing insects in tropical forests.
The insects are categorized into\dots

\plainpars
This is a general text describing fish in tropical forests.
The fishes are categorized into\dots

\nopars
This is a general text describing waters in tropical forests.
The waters are categorized into\dots

\kant[1-4]

\section{section another one}

This is a general text describing trees in tropical forests.
The trees are categorized into\dots

This is a general text describing insects in tropical forests.
The insects are categorized into\dots

This is a general text describing fish in tropical forests.
The fishes are categorized into\dots

This is a general text describing waters in tropical forests.
The waters are categorized into\dots

\end{document}


I can't reproduce the problem described in the comments for page breaks. The numbering continues fine for me.
With apologies for the poor quality, which is due to an Okular-on-X11 bug:


wow this is awesome. do you ever plan to turn this into a document package? anyway manage to add to overleaf doc.tex. Just fyi, this tag is fiddling with page numbers, sectional tags and \st{} tag which is usually used to strike out texts. At the beginning and end of each page, this is adding continuation of 3 numbers e.g. left middle and right top and botom Any idea how to solve that?

It is not possible to set pagesytle to empty as there are heavy styling that's being applied for images etc.

You might want to do some;thing about the indentation from \@afterheading with \nopars.  Easuest would be to set \parindent to 0pt for the duration.

@bonCodigo the pagestyle was just for the example because otherwise cropping the pdf to create the image includes the page number and a bunch of empty space. re. the other issue, will try to look later. I have a standard solution I use for this, too, but it doesn't use the new hooks. so I will post that if I can't get this to work.

@JohnKormylo it depends on the use case. the way I use this, I'm marking paragraphs for references to a text. I don't want to look indentation in that case. (but I also usually use indentfirst so it happens to look more consistent.)

@bonCodigo I just tested this with page numbers and page breaks and I can't reproduce the problem you describe. it might be best to ask a new question which includes a minimal example which reproduces the problem and links to this one. (I was going to suggest editing this question, but then you'll have this answer in the question which will make a mess.) \st isn't a standard command, so I don't know how you are defining it. you do need to turn off the numbering for section commands, which I would ideally like to fix but didn't have time earlier.

@bonCodigo please see edit. you probably want to tweak the formatting. this version is enabled automatically at \begin{document}, disabled at section divisions and re-enabled afterwards. you can still turn it off using \plainpars and reenable it with \nopars.

@cfr it is pretty amazing, isn't it. You should totally consider turning this into a package. This is really important to improve for both editing and presentation in many fields. Just fyi: before your update I managed to tweak your first version to to achieve what I want where it was still adding unwated numbers but without touching sectional/page commands. But I had to remove \st{} which is used to strike out text.

@cfr I will show you later screenshot of it. So when time comes for you to streamline this code, you can have a documentation as to what potential issues and how you solved it. I am sure you know this way better than me :)

@bonCodigo thanks. -:) and anything would be an improvement on my screenshot! I'm sure there are better solutions already. the packages for critical editions, maybe? those are pretty amazing.
